# Psexec to windows server 2012 only starts process, not GUI

Tags: windows, kodi, psexec

I need to run a program called Kodi in windows server 2012 from another machine, The startkodi.bat itself works correctly in the win server machine

```
C:\PSTools\psexec -u Administrator -p 123456 \\192.168.0.148 -s -d cmd.exe /c "C:\startkodi.bat"
```

But when i run this it only gives me

```
Starting PSEXESVC service on 192.168.0.148...
cmd.exe started on 192.168.0.148 with process ID 4460.
```

But when i remote it i dont see any instance of Kodi running,

BUT it does open a Kodi process in task manager...

Answer (score 0):

instead of using "cmd.exe /c" ... use explorer.exe "C:\startkodi.bat"

and depending on what is inside the batch file ... you may be a able  to do away with the bat ..

Simple example .. if you have 7zip installed in a default location ... open a command prompt and try:

```
\PSTools\psexec -u Administrator -p 123456 \\192.168.0.148 -s -d explorer.exe C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe
```

The problem may be the nature of the bat file, and what files are called inside the bat.  If you have an exe inside the bat .. try calling that EXE after the "explorer.exe" in the above example.

Comment: tried that  but it says `explorer.exe started on 192.168.0.148 with process ID 4556.` running this `C:\PSTools\psexec -u Administrator -p 123456 \\192.168.0.148 -s -d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Kodi\Kodi.exe"` gives me `C:\Program Files (x86)\Kodi\Kodi.exe started on 192.168.0.148 with process ID 2516.` but it's only process again.. not GUI

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution, it's because of Session 0 isolation.. Adding 2 after -i fixed it..

```
C:\PSTools\psexec -i 2 -d -u Administrator -p password \\serverip "C:\Program Files (x86)\Kodi\Kodi.exe"
```

Comment: Wait a sec... This command only works if i open remote desktop connection to that server.. Is there anyway to  make it work without rdesktop?